# Empty RealmResult Object

Tags: android, realm

I am having a scenario where i have an ArrayList of different ids. Now each id have more than one record in database, and the end result should be one list containing all the records of those ids. 
Is there any way i can combine them all in one RealmResult object?

I have two confusions here:

> 1. When i try to **initialize** Realm result, i couldn't find its constructor. It says no default constructor found.
> 2. AddAll method of RealmResult is deprecated.

Comment: The reason why i am hesitating to use ArrayList in place of RealmResult is that my App is syncing alot of data back to the server. So there may be alot of changes in the db while user is using the app.
So, i guess auto update of RealmResults can benefit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RealmResults<MyObj> results = realm.where(MyObj.class).in("id", arrayList.toArray()).findAll();
```

Comment: Thank you this will do .